# htaccess: Get rid of https and www

Tags: .htaccess, http, url, redirect, https

I am a newbie when it comes to rewrites and htaccess. I've done a bit of reading on this site but haven't found a solution to my exact problem. Basically what I want is to force all instances of **https://**, **https://www.**, and **www.** to just **http://**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.